# Duplicate class error in build.gradle when adding midtrans and chucker library

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

**Description**

I have a blank application that needs chucker to inspect requests and responses.

So I add chucker to dependencies.

```
debugImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0"
releaseImplementation "com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:4.0.0"
```

Sync and it runs successfully. But when I tried adding midtrans as payment gateway along with chucker, it breaks.

```
debugImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:2.0.0-SANDBOX'
releaseImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:2.0.0'
```

sync, hit run returns Duplicate class found ...

**Error Log**

```
Duplicate class com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.Chucker found in modules library-4.0.0-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0) and library-no-op-3.5.2-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2)
Duplicate class com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerCollector found in modules library-4.0.0-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0) and library-no-op-3.5.2-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2)
Duplicate class com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor found in modules library-4.0.0-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0) and library-no-op-3.5.2-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2)
Duplicate class com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor$Builder found in modules library-4.0.0-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0) and library-no-op-3.5.2-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2)
Duplicate class com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.RetentionManager found in modules library-4.0.0-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0) and library-no-op-3.5.2-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2)
Duplicate class com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.RetentionManager$Period found in modules library-4.0.0-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library:4.0.0) and library-no-op-3.5.2-runtime (com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op:3.5.2)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

Github link : https://github.com/ai-null/test-duplication-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `debugImplementation 'com.midtrans:uikit:2.0.0-SANDBOX'` includes `com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library-no-op`, which conflicts with `com.github.chuckerteam.chucker:library` due to their similar packages despite being different libraries.

Please try as follows:

```
debugImplementation('com.midtrans:uikit:2.0.0-SANDBOX') { exclude group: 'com.github.chuckerteam.chucker', module: 'library-no-op' }
```

Comment: Will try, so basically it ignores chucker inside midtrans sanbox library right? What about the release implementation?

Comment: Also, how did you know that the problematic ones is the sandbox? Checking the dependencies in repository? . Thank a lot for the answer tho, will try it

Comment: @AinulBedjo yes, chucker is a transitive dependency that midtrans brings, and with `exclude` it just ignores

Comment: @AinulBedjo you can launch `app:dependencies` gradle task to see the dependency tree, it shows what deps your libs bring, final versions of those deps, etc

Comment: with the release implementation you don't have exactly this conflict, as you included `library-no-op` for release, and midtrans also includes `library-no-op`, it's the same library (unlike debug, where artifacts were different while packages were same)

Comment: but there is a chance (in general, not exactly with these libs) to encounter another type of problems in case the api of chucker 4.0 is different from 3.5.2 without backwards compatibility. E.g. midtrans has been compiled with chucker 3.5.2 and calls a method that doesn't exist in 4.0 anymore that lead to `NoSuchMethodError` in runtime

Comment: it's working now, thank you very much sir